# Getting value from a firebase object using angularJS in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am trying to access user data in a controller via a service. The service returns the object correctly

```
{
  "$id": "9ecadf8e-a233-48ac-bebf-26b50ea2855d",
  "$priority": null,
  "branch": "London",
  "email": "manager@london.co.uk",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastLogin": 1467975594697,
  "lastLoginPrevious": 1467975348837,
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "role": "Manager"
}
```

when accessing the data from the controller I can access the `$id` successfully by using

```
$scope.userData = UserService.getUserData();
console.log($scope.userData.$id)
```

but when trying to access any other node such as role

```
$scope.userData = UserService.getUserData();
console.log($scope.userData.role)
```

I just get 'undefined' in the console. Obviously I am not doing this correctly but stuck on what I should try next.

Here is my service that retrieves the data from firebase

```
.service('UserService', ['$location', '$firebaseAuth','$firebaseObject', function ($location, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject) {
var userData = '';
var ref = new Firebase("https://firebase-url");
var authData = ref.getAuth();
var userUID = authData.uid;
var userRef = new Firebase("https://firebase-url/Users/" + userUID);
var userData1 = $firebaseObject(userRef);


return {

    getUserData: function () {
        if (userData == '') {
          userData =  userData1;
        }
        return userData;
    },

};
```

Comment: first check with this--console.log($scope.userData); if u able see the role as manager then for sure ur second console will display it.cross check that variable names also

Comment: There is no rocket science to get JSON object. If you are able to see whole object definitely you will be able to see that key pairs also. I still didn't understand why did you tagged it firebase and firebase database.

Comment: @Sa E console.log($scope.userData) returns the the json data in the question fine.

Comment: @Dev Qualwebs thats what I thought with JSON objects. The reason I have tagged as firebase and firebase-database is because I thought as I am getting the object from the database there maybe issues with asynchronous loading that is stopping me logging the "role"

Comment: Show how you retrieve the data from Firebase

Comment: Could be an async issue. Try loading the `$firebaseObject` in the controller: `$scope.userData = $firebaseObjet(ref)`, and the using `$scope.userData.$loaded(function() { // code });`. Once its loaded then set `userData1` inside the service `UserService.setUserData($scope.userData);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly be having an asynchronous issue. Here is an example of my code in a controller (*Firebase 3.0*):

```
// Gets reference to resources tree, SERVICE CALL
$scope.resourceNames = submissions.getResourceNames();
// Could be previously loaded, check
if(Object.keys($scope.resourceNames).length === 0 && $scope.resourceNames.constructor === Object) {
    // Get reference
    var resourceNameRef = firebase.database().ref("/resourceNames");
    firebase.database().goOnline();
    // Return JSON object of data at specified location
    $scope.resourceNames = $firebaseObject(resourceNameRef);
    // When resources loaded
    $scope.resourceNames.$loaded().then(function(data) {
        // Store into service, SERVICE CALL
        submissions.setResourceNames(data);
        // DO WHATEVER
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    });
} else {
    // WAS ALREADY LOADED
}
```

What I have done is check the service to see if the data has already been loaded (by another controller) and if it wasn't I call the data, wait for it to be loaded and then store it inside my service.

I can then use the data as I please inside the controller or in the view:

```
<p>
    {{resourceNames.$id}}
</p>
<p>
    {{resourceNames.name}}
</p>
<!-- etc -->
```